# Slurs and repeats in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, repeats, slurs

In a piece I have a bunch of:

```
   b( es b es b es)  b( es b es b es)
```

repeating stuff.

I'd like to just copy-paste whatever template and insert the notes once.

I could do:

```
\repeat unfold 6 { c d }
```

or:

```
\repeat unfold 2 { \repeat unfold 3 { c( d) } }
```

but the slurs will be incorrect.

So how can I add a slur to a note sequence?

Comment: What about `\repeat unfold 2 {b( \repeat unfold 2 { es b } es)}`? Is there some reason that won't work for you?

Comment: Works, but this pattern is repeating many times. I'd like to write the notes ONCE, and in the proposed solution it appears twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you remain quite simple something like this could work for you:

```
enslur =
#(define-music-function (n base count music)
   ((number? 1) (ly:duration? (ly:make-duration 3)) (number? 6) ly:music?)
   #{
     << \repeat unfold #n { s$base ( s$base * $(- count 2) s$base) } #music >>
   #})

\new Voice {
  \time 6/8
  \repeat unfold 2 { \enslur \repeat unfold 3 { c8 d } }
  \enslur 2 \repeat unfold 6 { c8 d }
  \enslur 4 4 3 \repeat unfold 6 { c4 d }
}
```

With more complex cases the problem is that slurs generally are started on the first note and ended on the last note, which means that if you want to add a slur you’d need to add the slur end event to the last note, which means having to determine the last note relevant to the slur.

Comment: Oh, nice. I am a developer, but when engraving music, I haven't yet tried lisp. Is there a good tutorial to start with?

Comment: Well, sometimes I need to add a `\f` mark to the first note. I guess that would quickly make things very complicated.

Comment: @pihentagy https://extending-lilypond.gitlab.io/en/index.html

Comment: Also adding `\f` on the first note can be done by `<>\f \repeat ...`, adding it on later notes can be done like `\after 8 \f \repeat ...`. Generally this `\enslur` could also be done like `<>( \after 8*5 ) \repeat ...`

Comment: Wait, wait! I think I can learn again from your <> syntax. Could you update your answer with this possibility?

Comment: And what about `\enslur \repeat unfold 3 { g!? fes }`, it marks all `g`s as accidentals.

Comment: @pihentagy This is unrelated to `\enslur ...`. You will see the same with `\repeat unfold 3 { g!? fes }`. The reason is that `?` and `!` set the `'force-accidental` property, as you can see here: `\displayMusic { g g? g! g!? }` (`!?` does the same as `?`, as `?` does *more* than `!`). You could do something like `\repeat unfold 3 { \volta 1 g? \volta 2,3 g fes }`. If you define `altFirst = #(define-music-function (n first others) (number? ly:music? ly:music?) #{ \volta 1 #first \volta #(iota (1- n) 2) #others #})` you could also write this as `\repeat unfold 3 { \altFirst 3 g? g fes }`.